# List all keys except for one in associative array

Tags: php

This should be simple, but I'm not getting the expected result. The browser either lists all the elements in the array (when I include the "!" operator) or doesn't list any elements (when I don't include the "!" operator). I'm just trying to list everything except for one element or to only list that one element. I can't get either way to work.

```
    $features = array(
    'winter' => 'Beautiful arrangements for any occasion.',
    'spring' => 'It must be spring! Delicate daffodils are here.',
    'summer' => "It's summer, and we're in the pink.",
    'autumn' => "Summer's over, but our flowers are still a riot of colors."
    );

    <h1>Labeling Array Elements</h1>
    <?php 
    foreach ($features as $feature) {
    if(array_key_exists('autumn', $features)) { 
    continue;
   } 
   echo "<p>$feature</p>";
   }    
   ?>
```

Comment: But the logic works with indexed arrays. My fiddle: main.xfiddle.com/de5f2f17/index_array_conditional.php. 

    <?php.$flowers = array('tulips', 'roses', 'daffodils', 'orchids', 'daisies'); 
    ?> 

    <?php foreach ($flowers AS $flower) { if ($flower == 'daffodils') { 
    continue; } echo '<li>' . ucfirst($flower) . '</li>'; if ($flower == 'orchids') 
    { break; } } ?>

Answer (score 2):

When you do the `continue` inside the loop simply because it exists in the array, it stops on the first iteration. That is always true.

Instead, you need to do something like this:

```
foreach ($features as $season => $description) {
    if ($season == 'autumn') {
        continue;
    }
    echo $description;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you may also using array_filter for this approach :

```
$features = array(
    'winter' => 'Beautiful arrangements for any occasion.',
    'autumn' => "Summer's over, but our flowers are still a riot of colors.",
    'spring' => 'It must be spring! Delicate daffodils are here.',
    'summer' => "It's summer, and we're in the pink.",
);

print_r(array_filter($features, function ($key) {
    return $key != 'autumn';
}, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY));
```

live demo : https://3v4l.org/Ctn8O